Quantitative version of open mapping theorem
This version of open mapping theorem says that for any surjective bounded linear map $T$ between two Banach Spaces $X$ and $Y$, there exists $a>0$ such that for each $y\in Y$ there is $x\in X$ such that $Tx=y$ and $|x|\leq a|y|$. I want to show that this last inequality implies that the image under $T$ of the open unit ball in $X$ is open in $Y$. How do I go about proving it?

Fix $x_0\in X$ with $|x|<1$, and let $y_0=Tx_0$. Let
$$
\delta=\frac1a\,(1-|x_0|)>0. 
$$
Suppose that $|y_0-y|<\delta$. By hypothesis there exists $x_1\in X$ with $Tx_1=y-y_0$ and
$$
|x_1|\leq a|y_0-y|<a\delta.
$$
Hence, with $z=x_1+x_0$
$$
|z|\leq|x_1|+|x_0|<a\delta+|x_0|=1.
$$
So $z$ is in the open unit ball of $X$ and $Tz=Tx_1+Tx_0=y-y_0+y_0=y$. Thus the whole open ball of radius $\delta$ around $y_0$ lies inside the image of the open unit ball by $T$, showing that $T$ maps the open unit ball to an open set.

Thanks a lot for the nice explanation.

Glad I could help!
